# Error when deploying a meteor app using mup deploy while npm install bcrypt

Tags: meteor, npm, meteor-up

I have an error when deploying a meteor app using `mup deploy`, well, in fact, I also get this error when I manually try to build the image with the Dockerfile generated by mup.

I guess the main error message (somewhere below in the log output) is:

**sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: not found**

Log output from `docker build -t my-app:build .`:

```
Removing intermediate container 3ac4d1150023
Step 7/7 : RUN cd  /built_app/programs/server &&     npm install --unsafe-perm
 ---> Running in 4a6faacefc21

> fibers@1.0.13 install /built_app/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js

`linux-x64-v8-4.5` exists; testing
Binary is fine; exiting

> meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 install /built_app/programs/server
> node npm-rebuild.js


> bcrypt@0.8.6 install /built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory '/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt_node.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib.node
  COPY Release/bcrypt_lib.node
make: Leaving directory '/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
bcrypt@0.8.6 /built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt
bindings@1.2.1 /built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/bindings
nan@2.2.1 /built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/nan

> bcrypt@1.0.3 install /built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! bcrypt@1.0.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@1.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-02-07T17_21_17_486Z-debug.log
npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 No license field.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 install: `node npm-rebuild.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the meteor-dev-bundle@0.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-02-07T17_21_17_559Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c cd  /built_app/programs/server &&     npm install --unsafe-perm' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

And the mentioned log files says:

```
...
1227 info build /built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt
1228 info lifecycle bcrypt@1.0.3~preinstall: bcrypt@1.0.3
1229 silly lifecycle bcrypt@1.0.3~preinstall: no script for preinstall, continuing
1230 info linkStuff bcrypt@1.0.3
1231 silly linkStuff bcrypt@1.0.3 has /built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules as its parent node_modules
1232 verbose linkBins bcrypt@1.0.3
1233 verbose linkMans bcrypt@1.0.3
1234 verbose rebuildBundles bcrypt@1.0.3
1235 info lifecycle bcrypt@1.0.3~install: bcrypt@1.0.3
1236 verbose lifecycle bcrypt@1.0.3~install: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
1237 verbose lifecycle bcrypt@1.0.3~install: PATH: /opt/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/.bin:/built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/.bin:/opt/nodejs/bin:/opt/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/built_app/programs/server/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
1238 verbose lifecycle bcrypt@1.0.3~install: CWD: /built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt
1239 silly lifecycle bcrypt@1.0.3~install: Args: [ '-c', 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build' ]
1240 info lifecycle bcrypt@1.0.3~install: Failed to exec install script
1241 verbose stack Error: bcrypt@1.0.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
1241 verbose stack spawn ENOENT
1241 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:33:16)
1241 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
1241 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
1241 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:862:16)
1241 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:222:5)
1242 verbose pkgid bcrypt@1.0.3
1243 verbose cwd /built_app/programs/server/npm
1244 verbose Linux 4.4.0-83-generic
1245 verbose argv "/opt/nodejs/bin/node" "/opt/nodejs/bin/npm" "rebuild"
1246 verbose node v4.8.7
1247 verbose npm  v4.6.1
1248 error file sh
1249 error code ELIFECYCLE
1250 error errno ENOENT
1251 error syscall spawn
1252 error bcrypt@1.0.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
1252 error spawn ENOENT
1253 error Failed at the bcrypt@1.0.3 install script.
1253 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
1254 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

meteor version: 1.4.4.2
node version:  v4.8.7
npm version: 4.6.1
mup version: 1.3.7
docker image: abernix/meteord:node-4.8.7-base

Any idea ...?
Which file is not found?
(And, I'm pretty sure that exactly the same config was working some while ago ...)
I really appreciate any suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app start needs `node-pre-gyp` because of `bcrypt` package:

> > bcrypt@1.0.3 install /built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt
>
> > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

However if you pay close attention, you will notice just above that another version of `bcrypt` is also installed and builds successfully:

> > bcrypt@0.8.6 install /built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt
>
> > node-gyp rebuild

Given the installation paths, it seems that `0.8.6` probably comes from a Meteor Atmosphere package ([`npm-bcrypt`](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/npm-bcrypt)), while `1.0.3` comes from `package.json` dependencies.

Therefore you should probably first try to sort out why you have 2 different installations of `bcrypt`, and if you can get rid of the `1.0.3` version.

In the most likely case that your app depends on `bcrypt` because of Meteor's `accounts-password` package, the latter will use a JavaScript version of `bcrypt` instead automatically if it is missing, so your app should not break by simply removing the npm version: `meteor npm uninstall --save bcrypt` (as mentioned by @AbhishekMaurya). However, as noted by @AbhishekMaurya's answer, the app start log will display a warning message suggesting to `npm install bcrypt` (which you have just undone). You can live with that warning if you accept the slight degradation in performance when your app uses the JavaScript implementation of `bcrypt`.

As for the root cause now, there was [a bug in Meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7568) that prevented `node-pre-gyp` being visible to `npm`. This should have been fixed in Meteor version `1.4.3`.

If not, you can try to make sure you use an "old" version of `bcrypt`, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8188#issuecomment-269402342): `meteor npm install --save bcrypt@0.8.7`

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! I really appreciate it, as it helps me understanding. Well, I really didn't notice that there was a different bcrypt version installed previously. I'll check this in detail. I remember that I installed bcrypt because of this warning message, and it did work in the past. I still try to find out what changed that broke it. Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall bcrypt, you will see warning but no major impact on application.